# Run through array and check values of <td> cells in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

**Scenario:**
I have a table with about 10 rows, each containing a  of class '.t3_dc'.

These cells will contain a value of between 1.0 and 9.9

For each td, I want to check if the score/value is between a certain amount and if so, change the colour. For example, < 7.0 would be red, 7-8 stay white, above 8 would be green.

I got this far after a few attempts but my biggest obstacle seems to be storing each  into an array and then running through and checking them individually.

```
 $(document).ready( function() {
 function scores () {
 var score = $('td.t3_dc').text();
 var num = parseFloat(score);

 alert(score)[0];

 if(num < 7 ) {
    $(score).css('color','green');
   }
 else {
    $(score).css('color','red');
   }
  };
    setTimeout(scores, 2000);
 });
```

Note: The timeout function exists as the table itself takes a couple of seconds to load on the page

**Q.** How can I loop through an array of 's and check each value, adding a colour as necessary?

Comment: Can you add your HTML structure to the question please?

Comment: it's a little difficult as its auto-generated html table - there are 10 rows and 2 <td>s per row. The td i'm interested in has the class mentioned above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imho, you don't need a timeout, the function will first fire when the page is loaded. Then loop the classes by using `each()` and check it's value.

```
$(function() {
  $('.t3_dc').each( function() {
    var elem = $(this) ,
        value = parseFloat( elem.text() );
    if( value < 7 ) {
      elem.css('color', 'red');
    }
    elseif( value > 8 ) {
      elem.css('color', 'green');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This made a lot of sense and simplified what I was trying to acheive

Answer (score 1):

use `$.each` for loop into yours elements.  try

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    function scores () {
        $.each($('td.t3_dc'),function(){
            if(parseFloat($(this).text()) < 7 ) {
                $(this).css('color','green');
            }
            else {
                $(this).css('color','red');
            }
        });

    };
    setTimeout(scores, 2000);
})
```

Comment: this *$.each(**'td.t3_dc'**, function(){* will not work. you either use *$.each(**$('td.t3_dc')**, function(){* or *$('td.t3_dc').each(function(){*

Comment: It's work fine with mine script. If you add $.each you have not need put into

Comment: all documentation I see and tested myself show $.each accepts an array or object by no selector. can you create a fiddle to show it working? i'm curious :)

Comment: :-) as much for me! sorry your are right. I have look an other answer :-). i am in stackexchange mobile app. thx man